# Retrieving image url from webpage

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-7, exception, html-agility-pack

```
string imgurlhard = doc.DocumentNode.
    Element("html").
    Element("body").
    Elements("div").Single(el => el.Attributes["id"].Value == "main").
    Elements("div").Single(el => el.Attributes["id"].Value == "onlineIntegrator").
    Elements("div").Single(el => el.Attributes["id"].Value == "results").
    Element("img").Attributes["src"].Value; 

MessageBox.Show(imgurlhard);
```

And here is the URL of webpage to retrieve:

```
http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=sin(x)&random=false
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong cause I catch a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Answer is easy and do this by yourself - what exactly line of code (which call) does cause the exception?

Comment: When you're getting an exception, Visual Studio will highlight the string causing it. To make that more clear, split your one-liner in separate calls (per string).

Answer (score 1):

```
var image = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("img")
    .Where(i => i.Attributes["class"] != null && i.Attributes["class"].Value == "traditionalForm")
    .Select(i => i.Attributes["src"].Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using HTMLagility.

```
string image = Doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='traditionalForm']//img['src'][1]").Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Edit

Now it should work.

Comment: And your code throws exception. Have you tested it before posting?